# How do I run multiple jar files from shell or cmd, and have all of them use different proxies?

Tags: proxy, java, socks, jar

I'm trying to run a jar file through a socks proxy. If I only had one jar, it would probably work to just change system variables, but I need to run like 20 jar files at the same time, all with different proxies. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set different proxy properties for each of them, as needed, for example in a shell script:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800 -jar path/to/program1.jar
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.101 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8801 -jar path/to/program2.jar
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.102 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8802 -jar path/to/program3.jar
```

Comment: java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response

Comment: Can you get any of the jar files run with a proxy? If yes, follow the same procedure for the others. If no, that's a different question, not an issue with multiple proxies, but a more basic issue of using a proxy at all.